# Текст и картинки накладываются на меню

Tags: header, position

Верстал сайт, у hesder `position: fixed;`, потом начал делать обычный список (ul, li), но некоторым элементам задал `position: absolute;`. Теперь при скроле в header залезают эти элементы (z-index не помогает).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Всё уже разобрался, надо было всего-лишь в header поставить `z-index: 1;`